# Very simple javascript example for getElementById. Why am I getting an error?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <script>
   var aMessage = document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML;
   console.log(aMessage);
  </script>
  <p id="aaa">Hello World!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I access the document, the console error I am getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

What am I missing?

Comment: Scripts are evaluated while the document is being parsed. When your script runs, your `<p>` element is not yet part of the DOM.

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  I thought it would look through the entire document.

Comment: It does look through the entire document _that has been parsed so far._ If that script ran after the document ready event, its location in the HTML would not matter.

Comment: May I ask why this one works though?

<script>
 var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 console.log(e);
</script>

If I put that before my DIV elements, it does return an index.

Comment: @xproofx - The Element.getElementsByTagName() method returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name. The subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element itself. The returned list is live, meaning that it updates itself with the DOM tree automatically. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have the script tag before the element. Try it the other way around:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <p id="aaa">Hello World!</p>
  <script>
   var aMessage = document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML;
   console.log(aMessage);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

It's usually advised to put the script tag at the very bottom of your page. There's also a couple of [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Listening_to_events_in_Firefox_extensions#Simple_DOM.c2.a0events) such as `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` that you can use to start your script once things have loaded

Comment: May I ask why this one works though?

<script>
 var e = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 console.log(e);
</script>

If I put that before my DIV elements, it does return an index.

Comment: @xproofx `.getElementsByTagName()` **always** returns a NodeList, but in that case it would be an empty one.